# Symfony YAML file concatenating parameters

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

Is there a way to do this:

```
//parameters.yml
app.basepath: 'C:\extrafolder'
app.specificpath: app.basepath + '\specificpath'
```

I want to concatenate strings to the app.basepath variable instead of repeating the string in app.basepath in all specific paths.

I have googled this but I´m a bit confused with the results

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to do something like that:

```
//parameters.yml
app.basepath: 'C:\extrafolder'
app.specificpath: '%app.basepath%\specificpath'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate using "+" in yaml/yml file. Instead you could use "%".
You can do it like:

```
//parameters.yml
app.basepath: 'C:\extrafolder'
app.specificpath: '%app.basepath%\specificpath'
```

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted the answer of Nikita Leshchev, because it was the first

Comment: Yeah, No Worries :)

Comment: The single quoted scalar `'%app.basepath%\specificpath'` has no special meaning in YAML. You can't concatenate using `+` and you can't concatenate `%` **in YAML** either. What you describe is entirely some interpretation done by symfony  of  the data that just happens to have been loaded from the YAML document.